# List of HTML Helpers you use

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have found Html Helpers extremely useful to simplify view pages code.

Apart from the ones included in the latest release of Asp.Net Mvc which one do you use?

How much you can reuse them in different projects  and are they linked only to html 
generation or did you put some custom logic inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib).[FluentHtml](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/mvcfluenthtml-fluent-html-interface-for-ms-mvc/).